# jvectormap smooth zoom in and out on click

Tags: jquery, zooming, jvectormap

Does anyone know if it's possible to make the zoom in jvectormap happen with a kind of animation, like a smoother dive in, and if yes how could I proceed? I have been looking for this all day long and I can't believe no one else has ever looked for this as I think it would make such a big difference to the already amazing plugin. I have been trying with the animate jquery function but it doesn't work with SVGs unless I use the raphael plugin. I can't use it as I really need to use jvectormap's markers functionality and I'm unfortunately not able to merge the two plugins.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @MasterAM The current version if Jvectormap.Version 2.0.3

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.

Zoom is happening when the svg group element (g tag under the svg tag) has new values for scale and translate. These values are set as an html attribute. If you set these values as css attributes then you can animate it using css transitions.

I tried on my firefox console. It works pretty good.

You might need to hide the native controls and write your own zoom in, zoom out methods. You will need to maintain scale for zooming, translate to keep the focus right.

This method might not work on older browsers as they don't support transform. You might think of checking transform and transition support and apply your implementation only when it is supported.